# Ghost unable to start due to missing dependencies

Tags: node.js, nginx, npm, ghost

My installation of Ghost on a DigitalOcean server running Ubuntu 14.04 suddenly stopped working. The webpage returns a 502 Bad Gateway. When I try `npm start` the console returns:

> ERROR: Ghost is unable to start due to missing dependencies:
>
> > Cannot find module 'hover.css'

I'm completely stuck. I read a few other threads on a similar issue, but none of the answers helped. I've tried removing node_modules and reinstalling node, plus clearing the cache in between. That doesn't work.

All this happened after I added a CSS transition to `img` tags on hover.

Comment: what do these commands yield?
 `which npm`   ,

`which node`  ,

and `echo $NODE_PATH` yield?